# Excel upload button

Tags: html, django

I created an excel upload button in my HTML file.

```
        <tr>
            <td><label for="id_excel">Excel: </label></td>
            <td class="fileUpload btn">
                <input type="file" name="excel" id="id_excel" class="upload" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Since I created this button to get Excel files, I want to prevent users to upload something else (for example docx or pdf). How can I limit the user to upload only Excel file type?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? please vote up arrow if so. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this in the 
It works fine for me, hope this will resolve your issue.

```
<script>
var fl = document.getElementById('id_excel');

fl.onchange = function(e){ 
    var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
    switch(ext)
    {
        case 'xls':
        case 'xlsx':
            alert('allowed');
            break;
        default:
            alert('not allowed');
            this.value='';
    }
};
    </script>
```

Comment: How do I use the said upload button to save the chosen file to the database?